# interpolation between two groups of points

Tags: python, pandas, python-2.7, numpy, interpolation

I have a data set with the following form:

```
     A    B     C     D     E
0  0.5  0.2  0.25  0.75  1.25
1  0.5  0.3  0.12  0.41  1.40
2  0.5  0.4  0.85  0.15  1.55
3  1.0  0.2  0.11  0.15  1.25
4  1.0  0.3  0.10  0.11  1.40
5  1.0  0.4  0.87  0.14  1.25
6  2.0  0.2  0.23  0.45  1.55
7  2.0  0.3  0.74  0.85  1.25
8  2.0  0.4  0.55  0.55  1.40
```

Here is code to generate this DataFrame with pandas:

```
import pandas as pd

data = [[0.5, 0.2, 0.25, 0.75, 1.25],
        [0.5, 0.3, 0.12, 0.41, 1.40],
        [0.5, 0.4, 0.85, 0.15, 1.55],
        [1.0, 0.2, 0.11, 0.15, 1.25],
        [1.0, 0.3, 0.10, 0.11, 1.40],
        [1.0, 0.4, 0.87, 0.14, 1.25],
        [2.0, 0.2, 0.23, 0.45, 1.55],
        [2.0, 0.3, 0.74, 0.85, 1.25],
        [2.0, 0.4, 0.55, 0.55, 1.40]]

df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['A','B','C','D','E'])
```

This data represent an outcome of an experiment where for each A B and E there is a unique value C

What I want is to perform a linear interpolation so that I get similar data for A= 0.7 for instance based on the values of A=0.5 and A = 1.
the expected output should be something like :

```
     A    B     C     D     E
0  0.5  0.2  0.25  0.75  1.25
1  0.5  0.3  0.12  0.41  1.40
2  0.5  0.4  0.85  0.15  1.55
3  0.7  0.2  xxx   xxx   1.25
4  0.7  0.3  xxx   xxx   1.40
5  0.7  0.4  xxx   xxx   1.55
6  1.0  0.2  0.11  0.15  1.25
7  1.0  0.3  0.10  0.11  1.40
8  1.0  0.4  0.87  0.14  1.25
9  2.0  0.2  0.23  0.45  1.55
10  2.0  0.3  0.74  0.85  1.25
11  2.0  0.4  0.55  0.55  1.40
```

is there a straightforward way to do that in Python? I tried using [the panda interpolate](https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/version/0.16/generated/pandas.DataFrame.interpolate.html) but the value I got didn't make sense.

Any suggestions?

Comment: What about SciPy interpolate? https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/interpolate.html

Comment: what is your expected output?

Comment: Why didn't the value you get make sense? What are you trying to achieve with the interpolation?

Comment: @Tomasz Bartkowiak how would  use SciPy  interpolate ?

Comment: I edited to the post to show the expected outcome

Comment: @cfd_aero You are trying to create a 1D interpolation function (mapping from A to C) so use interp1d (https://docs.scipy.org/doc/scipy/reference/generated/scipy.interpolate.interp1d.html#scipy.interpolate.interp1d). the argument x is the A column, the argument y is the C column.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Here is an example of how to create an interpolation function mapping values from column A to values from column C (arbitrarily picking 0.5 to 2.0 for values of A):

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from scipy import interpolate

# Set up the dataframe
data = [[0.5, 0.2, 0.25, 0.75, 1.25],
        [0.5, 0.3, 0.12, 0.41, 1.40],
        [0.5, 0.4, 0.85, 0.15, 1.55],
        [1.0, 0.2, 0.11, 0.15, 1.25],
        [1.0, 0.3, 0.10, 0.11, 1.40],
        [1.0, 0.4, 0.87, 0.14, 1.25],
        [2.0, 0.2, 0.23, 0.45, 1.55],
        [2.0, 0.3, 0.74, 0.85, 1.25],
        [2.0, 0.4, 0.55, 0.55, 1.40]]
df = pd.DataFrame(data,columns=['A','B','C','D','E'])

# Create the interpolation function
f = interpolate.interp1d(df['A'], df['C'])

# Evaluate new A (x) values to get new C (y) values via interpolation
xnew = np.linspace(0.5, 2.0, 10)
ynew = f(xnew)
print("%-7s %-7s"%("A","C"))
print("-"*16)
for x, y in zip(xnew, ynew):
    print("%0.4f\t%0.4f"%(x,y))
```

The result:

```
A       C
----------------
0.5000  0.8500
0.6667  0.6033
0.8333  0.3567
1.0000  0.8700
1.1667  0.7633
1.3333  0.6567
1.5000  0.5500
1.6667  0.4433
1.8333  0.3367
2.0000  0.5500
```

Comment: I think that's a step forward to get it, but in the data for each A = 0.5 there are three values of B, and for each value of B there is one value of C.

Comment: So, do you want to do a 2D interpolation (map A and B onto C)? Your question only mentions A ("What I want is to perform a linear interpolation so that I get similar data for A= 0.7 for instance based on the values of A=0.5 and A = 1"), please edit your question to clarify what you are after.

Comment: yeah basically I just needed to group the datafarme by 'C' then loop over and use the solution you suggested for each data point of of equal 'B'.